# Complex SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hi I am trying to write a SQL query but it is just to much for me.

I have records of refueling my car and I want to calculate prices for kilometer intervals.

Every record have actual kilometer state, how much liters I bought, price and currency and if I fill full tank. Consumption can be calculated only if I bought full tank, because only than I know how much liters I used.
So it should by like I am using diesel which cost 1.3 EUR/l with consumption 6.2 l/100km and I have 23l of it. Then I start using diesel which cost 1.38 EUR/l and I have 45l of it and then consumption changed to 6.5 l/100km, ...

I hope you know what I mean :)

So the result of the query should by like:

```
KmFrom    KmTo     PricePerKmEUR
156123    156874   0.1
156875    157147   0.12
```

This are the records what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE "CAR_Refueling"(
[Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
,[Date] DATE NOT NULL
,[KmTotal] INTEGER NOT NULL
,[Liters] NUMERIC(9) NOT NULL
,[PricePerLiter] NUMERIC(9) NOT NULL
,[CurrencyId] INTEGER NOT NULL
,[FullTank] BOOLEAN NOT NULL
,[Consumption] numeric(9)

);
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("1","2011-06-21","156327","70","32.88","8","1","0");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("2","2011-09-02","157036","52.28","1.359","9","1","7.37");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("3","2011-09-15","157832","52.32","5.47","13","1","6.57");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("4","2011-10-03","158830","61.48","2.44","14","1","6.16");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("5","2011-10-06","159054","14.38","2.46","14","1","6.42");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("6","2011-10-31","160070","20","1.456","9","0","0");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("7","2012-01-02","160367","6.765","1.478","9","0","0");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("8","2012-04-27","160414","19.59","1.48","9","0","0");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("9","2012-05-04","160808","66.36","187","16","1","6.43");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("10","2012-05-11","161767","56.37","9.99","15","1","5.88");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("11","2012-05-14","162088","21.07","1.337","9","1","6.56");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("12","2012-05-19","163043","65.12","1.439","9","1","6.82");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("13","2012-10-17","164029","65.67","1.203","9","1","6.66");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("14","2012-10-23","164916","51.14","1.369","9","1","5.77");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("15","2013-05-07","165937","62.45","1.329","9","1","6.12");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("16","2013-05-18","167098","15.05","1.329","9","0","0");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("17","2013-05-18","167359","63.47","1.138","9","1","5.52");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("18","2013-05-20","168335","56.83","1.309","9","1","5.82");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("19","2013-05-21","169051","38.43","1.369","9","1","5.37");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("20","2013-08-25","170096","65.12","1.399","9","1","6.23");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("21","2013-08-28","170636","30","1.43","9","1","5.56");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("22","2013-09-03","171471","30","1.349","9","0","0");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("23","2013-10-26","171953","61.62","1.136","9","1","6.96");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("24","2013-10-29","172196","13.02","1.278","9","1","5.36");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("25","2013-11-18","173101","55.92","1.359","9","1","6.18");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("26","2014-02-26","173963","50.49","1.309","9","1","5.86");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("27","2014-06-03","174667","49.78","1.349","9","1","7.07");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("28","2014-08-05","175501","62.78","1.289","9","1","7.53");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("29","2014-08-09","177195","55.74","1.279","9","1","6.36");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("30","2014-09-10","178266","66.22","34.9","8","1","6.18");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("31","2014-08-07","176318","51.93","1.278","9","1","6.36");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("32","2014-10-16","178888","41.04","1.339","9","1","6.6");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("33","2014-10-18","179498","42.28","1.239","9","1","6.93");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("34","2014-10-19","180037","34.71","1.214","9","1","6.44");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("35","2014-12-02","180860","55.79","1.229","9","1","6.78");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("36","2015-02-04","181579","53.26","1.089","9","1","7.41");
Insert  Into [CAR_Refueling] ([Id],[Date],[KmTotal],[Liters],[PricePerLiter],[CurrencyId],[FullTank],[Consumption]) Values("37","2015-02-17","182125","32.6","1.119","9","1","5.97");
```

Price per km can change in two cases:

1. I start using diesel with different price.
2. Consumption is changed.

I can calculate consumption just when I take full tank. So if I don't take full tank next time when I do, I have to sum liters and km. For example records from 2011-10-31 - 2012-05-04 => ((100 / (160808 - 159054)) * (20 + 6.765 + 19.59 + 66.36) = 6.426.

So one step is calculate consumptions => KmFrom | KmTo | Consumption.
Next step can by look at the tank as it is limitless and calculate LitersFrom | LitersTo | PricePerLiter.

And next step combine this together.

So this is calculated consumption with sumed liters.

```
    select KmFrom, KmTo, Consumption, 
     (select sum(Liters) from CAR_Refueling where KmTotal >= KmFrom and KmTotal <= KmTo) as Liters
    from
    (select (select max(B.KmTotal) 
                     from CAR_Refueling B 
                     where B.KmTotal < A.KmTotal and B.FullTank = 1) + 1 as KmFrom, 
                     A.KmTotal as KmTo, A.Consumption
     from CAR_Refueling A 
     where A.Consumption != 0 
     order by KmFrom)
```

And this gives me LitersFrom | LitersTo | PricePerLiter in unlimited tank.

```
SELECT Liters, LitersFrom, (LitersFrom + Liters - 1) AS LitersTo, PricePerLiter 
FROM (SELECT 
             (SELECT ifnull( sum( B.Liters ) , 0 )
                 FROM CAR_Refueling B 
                 WHERE B.KmTotal < A.KmTotal 
                ) AS LitersFrom, A.Liters, A.PricePerLiter 
            FROM CAR_Refueling A)
```

I am not sure if I should add +1 to liters and kilometers when I make the intervals.

In the end I want just insert actual state of kilometers in the car and it will calculate how much I drove and how much it cost me. And it can happen that I use for one part of the journey consumption 6.5 and for other 6.8 or I will use for one part diesel with price 1.36 and for other 1.24 or even combination both.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? I think self join can do the job.

**Update**: According to your explanation, I added a sorting by date to the query so now in inner subquery there is a generator of sequential Id's matching the date order

```
   select c2.[KmTotal]+1 as KmFrom,  c1.[KmTotal] as KmTo, 
   case c1.[FullTank] when 0 then 'NA' else round((c2.[PricePerLiter]*c1.   [Liters])/(c1.[KmTotal]-c2.[KmTotal]),2) 
   end as PricePerKm
   from (select (select COUNT(0) 
            from [CAR_Refueling] t1 
            where t1.Date <= t2.Date 
            ) as Id, KmTotal, Liters, PricePerLiter, FullTank from  [CAR_Refueling] t2  ORDER BY [Date] 
) c1, 

(select (select COUNT(0) 
            from [CAR_Refueling] t1 
            where t1.Date <= t2.Date 
            ) as Id, KmTotal, Liters, PricePerLiter, FullTank from   [CAR_Refueling] t2  ORDER BY [Date] 
 ) c2
where c1.id=c2.id+1
order by c2.id asc;
```

Please see [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2d000/34)

It is not completely working since you are refering to currency conversion table which is not included in your example. Also I was not sure whether you are willing to refer to your [Consumption] column values, or calculate consumption from Km and Liters - I went for the second option.

Comment: No sorry this is not it. KmTotal are ok if you sort them by date.

Comment: I have 37 different prices for diesel in my DB. And your query returns 35 records. So it can't be it. And also "NA" for price is not acceptable. There always have to be some price.